# How would one solve the equation $2^x=x^3-1$?

Tags: exponentiation, lambert-w

How would one solve the equation $2^x=x^3-1$?

I can't figure it out.

I managed to solve the easier $x^3 = 2^x$ using super-roots and the Lambert W function, but I can't seem to figure out how to solve it.

Comment: I'm afraid you need some numerical method.

Comment: Do you have reason to believe there is a closed form?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Not at all; I should probably mention that I mostly just mean getting something like $x = \textrm{something containing no other } x\textrm{'s}$, no matter how ugly it looks :P

Comment: The equation $2^x=ax^3-1$ is soluble for $a\approx .259$. I can tell you the solution, but I don't know how to get a closed value for $a$. The solution is $x = \frac{W(3e^{-3}) + 3}{\ln{2}}$. If this is useful I can write up an answer.

Answer (score 1):

First,
I am assuming that
you only want
real roots of
$2^x=x^3-1
$.

If $x < 1$,
then
$x^3-1 < 0$,
and $2^x > 0$,
so no negative roots.

Let
$f(x)
= 2^x-x^3+1
$.

According to Wolfy,
$f(x) > 0$
for $0 < x < 1.58833$,
$f(x) < 0$
for $1.58833 < x < 9.93693$,
and
$f(x) > 0$
for $9.93693 < x$.

$f'(x)
=\ln 2\ 2^x - 3x^2
$.

According to Wolfy,
which uses the Lambert W function,
the positive roots of this are
$x_1 = -\dfrac{2 W\left(-\frac{\log^{3/2}(2)}{2 \sqrt{3}}\right)}{\log(2)}
\approx 0.589665
$
and
$x_2 = -\dfrac{2 W_{-1}\left(-\frac{\log^{3/2}(2)}{2 \sqrt{3}}\right)}{\log(2)}
\approx 8.1768
$.

If $x > x_2$,
then
$f'(x) > 0$.
Therefore,
if
$x > 9.93693$,
$f(x) > 0$.

You can argue using the
higher derivatives of
$f(x)$
to get more elementary methods
of showing when
$f(x) = 0$,
but I will leave it at this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pencil and paper to give a quick statement of:

1. Whether there *is* a solution, and
2. The range the solution(s) must fall in if it/they exist.

First note that $2^x$ is positive for all $x$, and $x^3-1$ is negative for negative $x$.  So if there is a solution, it must be non-negative.

Next note that both the RHS and LHS of the equation are strictly increasing for positive $x$.  This simplifies things drastically.

Now make a table for the LHS and RHS of the equation for small values of $x$.  More precisely, let's define two functions: $$f(x)=2^x$$ $$g(x)=x^3-1$$ and make tables for each function, for small non-negative inputs.  (**Actually do this;** it's very simple.)

Observe which is greater, $f(x)$ or $g(x)$, for each value of $x$ that you check.  Observe where the comparison changes (and observe *that* it changes).

This will tell you:

1. That there *is* a solution, and
2. The consecutive positive integers between which the solution lies.